# Map constructor doesn't work on app destroy

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

My simple domain class:

```
class TestDestroy {
    String x
}
```

And a service:

```
class TestDestroyService implements DisposableBean {
    @Override
    void destroy() throws Exception {
        TestDestroy d = new TestDestroy(x: "x")
        println("Test destroy: ${d.x}")
    }
}
```

If I call the `destroy()` method from controller everything is fine and I get output:

```
Test destroy: x
```

The problem appears when the `destroy` is called on app shutdown, the output is:

```
2016-08-22 11:20:14.186:INFO:t.1:Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'grails'
Test destroy: null
2016-08-22 11:20:14.487:INFO:t.1:Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2016-08-22 11:20:14.496:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:stopped o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{ ...
```

This happens only for domain classes, for other groovy classes the constructor works as it should. If I set the property with setter it works.

Its generally dangerous for code which uses domain classes with map constructor and is called from `destroy()`

Setup:

```
groovy 2.4.4
hibernate4 4.3.6.1
jetty 8.1.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use grails bootstrap methods init and destroy.

```
def init = {
  //init code here
}

def destroy = {
//destroy code here
}
```

In destroy method you could perform any action.Also, if you want to seggregate you code from destroy create some service and then call that.

Comment: The destroy method is executed, so I don't need to invoke it from bootstrap. The DisposableBean's `destroy()` callback method is imho more readable and spring's standard way of implementing graceful shutdown. The problem is that groovy's Map constructor doesn't work after destroy.